Correlation between interval and nominal variables
I have a numeric variable with village sizes (in hectares) and a categorical variable with four soil types. I would like to investigate if soil type is associated with village size using R. I have plotted boxplots but now I would like to have some measure of association. I have read some answers here suggesting the use of Eta of ANOVA (correlation ratio). My size data are not normally distributed so I'm having doubts if I can use this. In package rstatix, function kruskal_effsize also gives the value of eta-squared but based on H. According to rstatix documentation "...eta-squared...indicates the percentage of variance in the dependent variable explained by the independent variable." Is it correct to use this measure to draw some conclusions about the relationship between the two variables?
If someone can shed some light on this I would really appreciate it.
I've got all Eta values, but I need to know if I can use them.

Thanks everyone for all your suggestions and help. I really appreciate it.
Meanwhile, I read some bibliography and decided to do a Kruskal-Wallis test since my data are not normally distributed and use epsilon-squared.

This is not an answer but a different idea: build a nonlinear model from one variable to the other: say you are looking to understand the "correlation between X and Y" (but they are nominal and interval data), then instead build a model hat Y =f(X) or hat X = g(y). Then rather assess the predictive goodness (by proper scoring rules) of f and g as  a drop-in for a correlation measure. The goodness would have to be evaluated on holdout sets (with e.g. repeated cross-validation). Not sure if there is a name for this.

Many similar Qs on site

SHORT
The $\eta$ and $\eta^2$ (eta and eta-squared) values are reasonably regarded as analogues to correlation and squared correlation.
LONG
Let's start by considering our familiar notion is of correlation in a scatterplot: how tight to a line the points hug in something like the plots below.

library(ggplot2)
library(MASS)
set.seed(2024)

N <- 100
XY1 <- MASS::mvrnorm(
  N,
  c(0, 0),
  matrix(c(
    1, 0.5, 0.5, 1
  ), 2, 2)
)
XY2 <- MASS::mvrnorm(
  N,
  c(0, 0),
  matrix(c(
    1, 0.9, 0.9, 1
  ), 2, 2)
)

d <- data.frame(
  x = c(XY1[, 1], XY2[, 1]),
  y = c(XY1[, 2], XY2[, 2]),
  Correlation = rep(c("Modest Correlation", "High Correlation"), c(N, N))
)
ggplot(d, aes(x = x, y = y, col = Correlation)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(cols = vars(Correlation), scales = "free") +
  theme(legend.position = "off")

Then the sign of the correlation can describe if the line points up (positive correlation) or down (negative correlation), with the magnitude describing the strength of the relationship.
The magnitude of what we call Pearson correlation (the usual one) turns out to be equivalent to taking the square root of the $R^2$ value of regressing either variable on the other using an ordinary least squares linear regression with an intercept, when $R^2$ is calculated by the following equation.
$$
R^2=1-\left(\dfrac{
\overset{N}{\underset{i=1}{\sum}}\left(
y_i-\hat y_i
\right)^2
}{
\overset{N}{\underset{i=1}{\sum}}\left(
y_i-\bar y
\right)^2
}\right)
$$
That $R^2$ calculation is also equivalent to taking the squared Pearson correlation between the true a values and values predicted by the ordinary least squares linear regression with an intercept, perhaps explaining the name $R^2$.
You brought up using an ANOVA. ANOVA turns out to be equivalent to ordinary least squares linear regression with an intercept, using some clever encoding of the categories to give the independent variables. However, then you have your regression, and you can calculate $R^2$ and $\sqrt{R^2}$ to get a measure of association.
This $R^2$ value from the ANOVA regression is the ANOVA $\eta^2$, and $+\sqrt{\eta^2}$ is a viable generalization of Pearson correlation. I say to take the positive square root because the sign no longer makes much sense (there is no longer a line through a scatter plot that either slopes up or down), yet people tend not to like negative numbers. It also relates to the idea of taking the correlation between true and predicted values in a regression, where we should hope for a positive correlation and are guaranteed of a non-negative correlation by ordinary least squares linear regression with an intercept.
None of this has made any reference to distribution assumptions. Certain techniques of hypothesis testing and calculating confidence intervals make distribution assumptions, but the pure calculation of correlation does not make any assumptions. If you just want a simple analogue of the common Pearson correlation, yes, $\eta$ seems like your friend.
This says about the same as what I have written here.

This says about the same and perhaps should be regarded as a duplicate.

ANOVA (which is mathematically equivalent to OLS regression) does not assume that the dependent variable is normally distributed. It assumes that the errors are. You can check this easily enough. It's part of the usual output from lm in R. You should also check the other assumptions.
If they are violated, you can use tools such as robust regression (there are various types) or quantile regression, neither of which make assumptions about the error distribution.
Personally, I am more familiar with $R^2$ from regression; I am not sure if that is equivalent to $\eta ^2$ or not. Is there a reason to use ANOVA instead of regression?  (They are mathematically equivalent but the format of the output varies).

It always bothers me to see people say that quantile regression makes no assumptions about error distribution, because neither does minimization of square loss unless we see it as maximum likelihood estimation with a Gaussian likelihood. But then quantile regression has the same kind of equivalence with maximum likelihood estimation with a Laplace likelihood.

@Dave I suspect "quantile regression" is usually carried out for a set of quantiles of interest: that's not MLE because the implied likelihood varies with the quantile.

And minimizing square loss elicits conditional means, whether the conditional distribution is Gaussian or not.
